# Vue3 Ghost script setup api call with page filter

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, ghost-blog

I'm still getting a bit familiar with the Vue3 script setup syntax.
For which I am trying to understand how integrate pagination with a dynamic API call.

```
  <script setup>
    import GhostContentAPI from '@tryghost/content-api'

    import { ref } from "vue";


    const api = new GhostContentAPI({
      url: 'https://demo.ghost.io',
      key: '22444f78447824223cefc48062',
      version: "v5.0"
    });

const pagestart = ref(1);
let posts = [];

const allposts = async () => { 
   await api.posts
    .browse({
      page: pagestart.value,
      limit: "6",
      include: "tags,authors,slug",
    })
    .then((response) => {
     let posts = response
     console.log(posts)
})
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    })
  };

watch(pagestart, (newValue, oldValue) => { 
    console.log(newValue, oldValue); 
    if(newValue !== oldValue){
       allposts();
    }
}); 

onMounted(() => {allposts(); })


    
    </script>
```

So what i don't understand is how do i make the call refresh when the current page is changed. so far i can see in the console that the api call changes but the content is not refreshed nor is it loaded in on page load

Comment: Yes If you want to `watch` reactivity and perform some action you can use `watcher`. Check if `newValue` diff then `oldValue` and call your api

Comment: How would i wrap the API call in that watcher ?

watch(pagestart, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  console.log(newValue, oldValue);
});

Answer (score 1):

You can try following to have api call in `watch`

```js
<script setup>
    import { ref } from "vue";

    const api = new GhostContentAPI({
      url: 'https://demo.ghost.io',
      key: '22444f78447824223cefc48062',
      version: "v5.0"
    });

    const currentpage = ref(1)

    const allposts = () => { 
      return await api.posts
        .browse({
          page: currentpage.value,
          limit: "6",
          include: "tags,authors,slug",
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
        })
      };

    watch(currentpage, (newValue, oldValue) => { 
        console.log(newValue, oldValue); 
        if(newValue !== oldValue){
           allposts();
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

In watcher, we check for reactive `currentPage` whether its value changes or not and if it does we do api call from watcher.

This way call refreshes every time `currentPage` is changed.

Comment: Hi i've updated the question based on your answer, since i have the call working but the content is not dynamically displayed when the watcher gets fired

Answer (score 0):

What i ended up using:

still had to wrap the await in a async function
still had to match the response with the posts.value

```
<script setup>
import GhostContentAPI from "@tryghost/content-api";

import { ref, watch } from "vue";

const api = new GhostContentAPI({
  url: 'https://demo.ghost.io',
  key: '22444f78447824223cefc48062',
  version: "v5.0"
});

const pagestart = ref(1);

const allposts = async () => {
  await api.posts
    .browse({
      page: pagestart.value,
      limit: "6",
      include: "tags,authors,slug",
    })
    .then((response) => {
      posts.value = response;
      console.log(posts);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
};

watch(pagestart, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  console.log(newValue, oldValue);
  if (newValue !== oldValue) {
    allposts();
  }
});

const posts = ref(allposts());
</script>
```